# How to open new Tmux pane horizontally with 20% tall?

Tags: tmux

Normally I have to create a new horizontal pane with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd> and then resize it down with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

How can I configure tmux to do this with just one command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I can bind 1 shortcut to do 2 commands separated by ;

```
bind + split-window -v -c "#{pane_current _path}"\; resize-pane -D 20
```

Edit: Thank to Meuh's help, now it looks like this

```
bind + split-window -v -p 20
```

Edit2: `-p` flag is deprecated in tmux 3.4

```
bind + split-window -l '20%'
```

Comment: Note, you can specify a percentage size for the new pane with option `-p 20` to the `split-window` command.

Comment: That's great, thank you